# Cómo hacer que un navbar menú ocupe todo el ancho y alto de la pantalla en dispositivos móviles

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, bootstrap

estoy diseñando una landing page haciendo uso de bootstrap 3. Estoy intentando que mi navBar menú ocupe todo el ancho y alto de la pantalla cuando la pagina se este usando en dispositivos móviles, pero hasta el momento he logrado que sea asi. 
Este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
      <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-offset="50">

       <section class="navbar navbar-fixed-top custom-navbar bg-trans" role="navigation" id="navbar_menu">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" id="toggle_button">
            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="nav-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo" title="logomain" id="main_logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu_collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="list_options">
            <li class="list_options_Li"><a href="index.php" class="smoothScroll itemLi">HOME</a></li>

             <li class="dropdown list_options_Li" id="li_main_drop">

              <a class="dropdown-toggle itemLi" data-toggle="dropdown" id="a_dropdown">LEISTUNGEN  <i class="fa fa-angle-down" id="icon_mobile"></i>
              </a>

              <hr class="line_dropdown_mobile fadeInLeft">

              <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-main" style="background-color: white; color: black; width: 200px !important;">
                                    <li class="dropdown_li"><a href="webdesign.php" class="itemUlLi">Webdesign & Entwicklung</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown_li"><a href="corporate-design.php" class="itemUlLi">Corporate Design</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown_li"><a href="online-marketing.php" class="itemUlLi">Online Marketing</a></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown_li"><a href="lieferdienst.php" class="itemUlLi">Lieferdienst Webshop</a></li>
                                </ul>
                </li>
            <li class="list_options_Li"><a href="projekte.php" class="smoothScroll itemLi">PROJEKTE</a></li>
            <li class="list_options_Li"><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll itemLi">AGENTUR</a></li>
            <li class="list_options_Li"><a href="kontakt.php" class="smoothScroll itemLi">KONTAKT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
          @media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 320px) 
        {

         .just_text
        {
            margin-left: 2px !important;
            margin-right: 20px !important;
        }

        .title_left
        {
            text-align: center !important;
        }

        #main_logo
        {
          padding-top: 0px !important;
          padding-bottom: 0px !important;
          padding-left: 25px !important;
        }

        #navbar_menu 
        {
            border-bottom: 0;
            background: transparent; /*0 0*/;
        }

        #dropdown-main 
        {
        background-color: white !important;
        background: white !important;
        padding-right: 0px !important;

        }

        .itemUlLi
        {

        color: black !important;
        font-size: 18px !important;

        }

        #list_options
        {
            margin-top: 0px !important;
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            padding-bottom: 20px !important;
        }

        .itemLi
        {
            font-size: 20px !important;
        }

        .list_options_Li
        {
        padding-bottom: 30px !important;
        }

        .dropdown_li
        {
            padding-top: 15px !important;
        }

        #list_options 
        {
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            padding-bottom: 0px !important;
            margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        }

        #services_title div.section-title
        {
            padding-right: 11px !important;
            padding-left: 11px !important;
        }


        #icon_mobile
         {
         display: inline-block !important;
         }

        #dropdown-main
        {
            padding-right: 0px !important;
            margin-right: 0px !important;
            padding-top: 15px !important;
            width: 100% !important;
            padding-left: 30px !important;
        }

        .navbar-toggle
        {
            margin-top: 20px !important;
            margin-right: 25px !important;
        }

        .collapse.in
        {
            background-color: white !important;
            position: relative !important;
            top: 0 !important; 
            padding-left: 20px !important;
            height: 600px !important;
        }

        .collapse.in ul
        {
            background-color: white !important;
        }

        .collapse.in ul li a
        {
            color: black !important;
        }

         .display_line
          {
            display: block !important;
            color: blue !important;
            font-weight: bold !important;
            width: 20% !important;
            margin-left: 10px !important;
            margin-right: 0% !important;
            margin-top: 0% !important;
            margin-bottom: 0% !important;
            border-top: 2px solid blue !important;
            text-align: left !important; 
          }


        } /* */
```

el boton con clase navbar-toggle es el encargado de abrir y cerrar el menu en versiones moviles. Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando se le de click al boton para abrir el menu, este me abarque todo el resto de la pantalla, pero que no tape el logo ni el boton navbar-toggle. 
Hasta los momentos, cuando le dio click al boton navbar-toggle se abre el menu pero solo abarca hasta la mitad, y si abro el dropdown con id=dropdown-main de igual forma el menu no me abarca toda la pantalla sino que queda igual a la mitad y las opciones que se rodaron aparecen pero haciendo scroll...
Cómo podria hacer para que me ocupe todo el alto de la pantalla?

Imagen de como luce actualmente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta:
 .navbar-collapse {
    height: 100vh;
}

Answer (score 2):

Yo he resuelto el ancho del menú metiendolo dentro de un DIV con la clase "col-12" se ajusta perfectamente, es la versión 4 de Bootstrap.

```
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-info text-white">

      <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/education-255/120/Atom-Icon-512.png" alt="Logo de Empresa" height="25">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menú</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Activo</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Características</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Precios</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Desactivado</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

intenta con esto

```
#menu_collapse {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

con el vh lo fuerzas a que sea del porte de viewport en cambio con el % tienes que tomar encuenta que el contenedor padre tiene que tener el 100% del contenido por eso lo mas probable que no te dejo . espero que te sirva , saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tal y como veo, puedes poner el id="menu_collapse" en position absolute

```css
#menu_collapse {
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_collapse ">
  ul>li*5 ... etc
</div>
```

Comment: No me ha servido lastimosamente, incluso ahora queda más pequeño.

Comment: Tampoco me ha funcionado la segunda opción, se queda como al principio, a la mitad... voy a subir una imagen de como luce actualmente el menu en la versión movil.

Comment: en el id = menu_collapse

Comment: añadiendo position absolute me queda más pequeño, se redujo.